# .desktop file stopped working after changing default shell from bash to zsh

Tags: fedora, zsh, .desktop

i have been using this desktop file `pluto.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/home/user/Software/Installed/Pluto/pluto_startup.sh
Icon=/home/user/Software/Installed/Pluto/Pluto.svg
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Pluto
Categories=Development;IDE;
```

pointing to the executable `pluto_startup.sh`, which contains julia code launching Pluto (julia notebooks in a browser):

```
#!/bin/env julia
cd("/home/user/Software/Installed/Pluto")
using Pkg
Pkg.activate(".")
using Pluto
Pluto.run()
```

Unfortunately this stopped working after i changed my default shell from bash to zsh. Running `desktop-file-validate` did not return any errors and `gtk-launch pluto` still works (i can also run `pluto_startup.sh` directly). However, when i click on the icon in my GNOME dash, a terminal opens and immediately closes and Pluto is not launched. I have tried using

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "sh -c 'home/user/Software/Installed/Pluto/pluto_startup.sh'"
```

instead as well as putting the content of `pluto_startup.sh` into a seperate julia file, which then gets called by a file containing only

```
#!/bin/zsh
julia -i /home/user/Software/Installed/Pluto/pluto_startup.jl
```

but both attempts failed.

Any idea what might cause this problem or how i can troubleshoot it?

Basic OS info:

```
Fedora Linux 38 (Workstation Edition) x86_64
GNOME 44.1 on Wayland
```

Comment: To debug the problem, I suggest to add code to your scripts that will write some debug output to a file with an absolute file name, e.g. `/tmp/output.txt`, to show if the script is actually run. (Probably not related to your problem: Naming executable files like `xyz.sh` or `xyz.jl` is bad practice. The file name `pluto_startup.sh` is even misleading because it is not a shell script. If you don't absolutely need features of `zsh`, I suggest to write scripts for `sh` or `bash`, even if you use `zsh` as your interactive shell.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I was a little desperate and tried a few things quick and dirty. Specifying the link to the interpreter explicitly seemed to have fixed the issue for me.

Comment: The purpose of this site is not only to find a solution for you personally but also to provide a reference of questions and solutions for people who migfht have a similar problem. That's why it might be good to [edit] your question and add more details. I just noticed `#!/bin/env julia` On my system there is no `/bin/env` but `/usr/bin/env`. To me it is not fully clear why the script `#!/bin/zsh` `julia -i /home/user/Software/Installed/Pluto/pluto_startup.jl` fails. Maybe because `julia` is not in `PATH`?

Comment: What do think would be good to add specifically? 
`julia` is in `PATH` both for bash and zsh. Like i said, i didn't change anything about the way pluto is started and i am still not sure what causes this behaviour.

Comment: For example you wrote "both attempts failed". What exactly did you do? How exactly did it fail? Or add some debug output to your scripts and show the resulting output.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution/workaround for this problem: Simply giving the absolute path to the interpreter of the file `pluto_startup.sh` (which i also renamed to `pluto_startup.jl` for clarity) to something like `#!/<abs-path-to-julia-binary>` seems to have fixed the problem for me.

Comment: The best name would be simply `pluto_startup` without any `.jl` or `.sh` because the scripting language is an irrelevant implementation detail.